# Checking multicollinearity with generalized additive model in R

Tags: r, multicollinearity, generalized-additive-model, variance-inflation-factor

I am trying to check multicollinearity with GAM using VIF in R. 
Should I use vif from the package car ? or Is it right way to check vif using vif.gam from package mgcv::helper:: ? 
It gives quite different results and with vif.gam result, it does not show vif results with smoothed variables. 
How should I tell whether it has multicollinearity problem or not with vif value ? 
Also, I wonder how concurvity and multicollinearity are different?

Answer (score 6):

The VIF in package **car** is computing a generalised VIF (GVIF), which aims to account for the fact that multiple columns in the model matrix and multiple coefficients may be associated with a single covariate in the model (think polynomial terms).

It produces gibberish, however, for models estimated via `mgcv::gam()` as it fails to identify properly all the terms that include a given covariate.

The `mgcv.helper::vif.gam()` function computes a classic VIF for the **parametric** terms in a model only.

To illustrate, I modify an example from the **mgcv.helper** `README.md`

```
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)
library(mgcv.helper)

set.seed(101)

N <- 100
x1 <- runif(n=N)
x2 <- runif(n=N)
x3 <- runif(n=N) + 0.9*x1 - 1.75*x2

df <- data.frame(x1 = x1,
                 x2 = x2,
                 x3 = x3) %>%
mutate(y = rnorm(n=N,
                 mean = 1 - 2*x1 + 3*x2 - 0.5*x3,
                 sd = 0.5))

## as per README.md except use a smooth of x3
fit1 <- gam(data=df, y ~ x1 + x2 + s(x3))
```

Now we can compute the VIFs using **car** and **mgcv.help**:

```
> car::vif.default(fit1)
       GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
x1 56758.74  0             Inf
x2 56758.74  0             Inf
x3 56758.74  0             Inf
> mgcv.helper::vif.gam(fit1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  variable   vif
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 x1        2.05
2 x2        4.90
```

As you can see, the `car::vif.default()` gets this all wrong as it't can't identify even the parametric terms in the model. `vif.gam()` is computing the classical VIF for the parametric terms only.

However, for GAMs, checking for co**linearity** is not sufficient. As we're now fitting smooth functions we need to determine whether the smooth function of one variable can be produced using a combination of the smooths of the other terms in the model. I.e. we need to think about concurvity.

As to whether a VIF is too large or not, there are only rules of thumb to follow. It is up to you, I believe, to decide if the degree of collinearity is too much. A useful way to think of the VIF is as follows: the square root of the VIF for the $j$th covariate indicates by how much the confidence interval for $\hat{\beta}_j$ is expanded relative to uncorrelated data (if such data could exists). So, in the information returned by `vif.gam()`, the confidence interval for `x1` is inflated by about 1.4 times, and that for `x2` by 2.2 times.

But this of course is not considering any collinearity with `x3`, which is also estimated to a linear term (it uses 1 degree of freedom). If we refit with  a linear term for `x3` and recompute the VIFs we get

```
> mgcv.helper::vif.gam(fit2)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  variable   vif
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 x1        2.05
2 x2        4.90
3 x3        5.39
```

which doesn't change the VIFs for the other two variables of course, but does highlight the limitations of only considering the strictly parametric terms.

If we use `concurvity()` from the **mgcv** package, we note the strong collinearity for `x3`:

```
> concurvity(fit1)
              para     s(x3)
worst    0.8941263 0.8286386
observed 0.8941263 0.8145965
estimate 0.8941263 0.6325963
```

as well as that of the parametric terms, but we are not able to separate the collinearity in the parametric terms into individual estimates for `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: A small note about mgcv.helper. I needed to use: librarian::stock("samclifford/mgcv.helper", lib =  tempdir()) or you can use remotes::install_github("samclifford/mgcv.helper"). Meyer (2021:https://geomoer.github.io/moer-bsc-project-seminar-SDM/unit99/student_tutorials-02b_GAM_Meyer.html) uses the usdm package with VIF threshold of 5, and I believe Zuur et al. (2009) "rule of thumb" is between 5-7.