# Concurvity in additive modelling. Parametric term?

Tags: multicollinearity, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am modelling a outcome in gam were two variables (x1 and x2) are continuous and the other four are factors. I have a suspicion that x1 and x2 might be collinear so I want to check that. As I understand I need to check with concurvity. The figures of approx. 0.37 which I expect to be OK, or?

```
   A1 <- gam(y~ s(x1) + s(x2), data= df, method = "REML")

concurvity(A1)
                 para     s(x1)     s(x2)
worst    1.604547e-25 0.3765562 0.3765562
observed 1.604547e-25 0.3637563 0.2497401
estimate 1.604547e-25 0.2926522 0.2767589


 > concurvity(A1, full = FALSE)
    $worst
                  para        s(x1)        s(x2)
    para  1.000000e+00 9.035414e-26 7.145648e-26
    s(x1) 9.194812e-26 1.000000e+00 3.765562e-01
    s(x2) 7.033065e-26 3.765562e-01 1.000000e+00

    $observed
                  para        s(x1)        s(x2)
    para  1.000000e+00 4.660693e-34 4.259220e-30
    s(x1) 9.194812e-26 1.000000e+00 2.497401e-01
    s(x2) 7.033065e-26 3.637563e-01 1.000000e+00

    $estimate
                  para        s(x1)        s(x2)
    para  1.000000e+00 3.875674e-28 3.293079e-28
    s(x1) 9.194812e-26 1.000000e+00 2.767589e-01
    s(x2) 7.033065e-26 2.926522e-01 1.000000e+00
```

The problem is that when I include my factors I get high concurvity with the parametric terms which I cannot understand. To check, I have made x3-x6 as completely random variables (0 and 1) and I still get the high concurvity.

```
df$x3 <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size=368)
df$x4 <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size=368)
df$x5 <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size=368)
df$x6 <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size=368)

df$x3 <- as.factor(df$x3)
df$x4 <- as.factor(df$x4)
df$x5 <- as.factor(df$x5)
df$x6 <- as.factor(df$x6)


A2 <- gam(y~ s(x1) + s(x2)  +x3 +x4+ x5 + x6, data= df, method = "REML")


> concurvity(A2)
              para     s(x1)     s(x2)
worst    0.8005751 0.3817906 0.3921831
observed 0.8005751 0.3701165 0.3551481
estimate 0.8005751 0.2994385 0.2887118


> concurvity(A2, full = FALSE)
$worst
              para        s(x1)        s(x2)
para  1.000000e+00 9.035414e-26 7.145648e-26
s(x1) 9.038433e-26 1.000000e+00 3.765562e-01
s(x2) 7.125601e-26 3.765562e-01 1.000000e+00

$observed
              para        s(x1)        s(x2)
para  1.000000e+00 3.565108e-34 1.338613e-31
s(x1) 9.038433e-26 1.000000e+00 3.393421e-01
s(x2) 7.125601e-26 3.637036e-01 1.000000e+00

$estimate
              para        s(x1)        s(x2)
para  1.000000e+00 3.875674e-28 3.293079e-28
s(x1) 9.038433e-26 1.000000e+00 2.767589e-01
s(x2) 7.125601e-26 2.926522e-01 1.000000e+00
```

**Can someone please explain why and what I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on GAMs by any stretch of the imagination, but I've been wrestling with them for a few months now.  My understanding of the issue of high concurvity in the parametric terms is this: since the parametric terms are estimated with a very simple function (linear) it is very easy to explain that function in terms of the more complex smooths in the model.  There is another function in the package `mgcv.helper` called `vif.gam()` that can calculate the variance inflation factors for the parametric terms... Unfortunately, it doesn't work for factor variables that require a GVIF (generalized variance inflation factor).  I found that it wasn't to hard to modify the `vif()` function in the `car` package to work for `gam` objects, though.  You just have to make it sure it recognizes the difference between parametric terms and smooth terms.

Take everything I said with a grain of salt.  I'd love for a true expert to weigh in, as I would like to feel more confident about this as well.

## Edit:

You will probably find this answer very helpful: [vif.gam()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370869/checking-multicollinearity-with-generalized-additive-model-in-r/371043#371043)